# What does "Non-constructor value passed to NewPromiseCapability" mean?

Tags: javascript, promise, q, es6-promise

I used Kris Kowal's Q, but now I'm trying to lighten the number of libraries, so I'm switching to native Promises (but yes, I'm using a polyfill to support internet explorer).

Most of my functions return promises, but there was a place where I wanted to expose Q.all as being supplied by my own code.  When I did:

`MyLibrary.prototype.all = Promise.all;`

..., and used it (`myLibrary.all([...]).then(...)`), I got "Non-constructor value passed to NewPromiseCapability."  What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

MyLibrary never properly inherited from Promise, so the context ("this") was lost.

To fix, instead of doing `myLibrary.all([...])`, I'm just using Promise.all([...]).

I suppose another option could have been to bind .all() to Promise by `MyLibrary.prototype.all = Promise.all.bind(Promise)`